# /usr/local/Cellar is completely empty. I expected libraries

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have been using homebrew for some time now and have never had problems. Now I am wanting to link some libraries (GLEW, GLFW) for a C++ project. I was told to look in `/usr/local/Cellar` but is completely empty (ls -a yields only `.`, `..`) I have looked all over the `/usr/local` directory for them, but to no avail. I have tried reinstalling them as well as restarting my computer.
If anyone has some tips on this, I would be very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: On Apple Silicon, installation occurs into `/opt/homebrew` whereas on Intel machines it's `/usr/local`